# disabling an array of keys events with jquery

Tags: jquery, onkeydown

I want a function to occur only if and actual character can by typed, e.g. tab, caps lock, etc should not activate said function. My solution was to create an array of key ids and if the keyup action was a key in this array, then the function would not activate.

This is what I have:

```
$(field).keydown(function(e){
    keys = [9,16,17,18,19,20,27,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,144,145];
    if($.inArray(e.which,keys) !== -1) {
       // activate function
    }
});
```

So 1. I was wondering what is wrong with this code, for some reason it does the exact opposite of what I want, i.e. it only happens id tab, or control, etc are pressed. I have played around with it, but with no luck.

And 2. Is this even the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

... you list keys that you want not to have an effect, but `inArray` only returns -1 if the target was not found in the array, and you only execute if `inArray` doesn't return -1. So if it's not in the inactive keys, `inArray` returns -1, and then the `!==` comparison returns `False`, and your function is not executed. Basically, change `!==` for `==`